# How to add missing dates to the result table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table:

```
accdate (DATETIME) | value (INT)
-------------------+------------
                   |
```

The accdate-column contains datasets on hour-granularity. That means, there are datetimes in the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:00:00`. If I view the table using `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY accdate ASC` I get an ordered table by accdate. But mytable does not contain all possible dates and hours between the first row and the last (some dates are missing in the times my program is not running). I want to have default-values for all possible date+hour-combinations between the first and the last row.

I know this can be solved by using a LEFT JOIN with another table, that contains all possible dates in this range. **But how do I construct such a table in a SQL-Statement?** I think it is not senseful to populate the table with dummy data, if I can resolve the problem in the query.

Example:

```
accdate (DATETIME)   | value (INT)
---------------------+------------
2011-11-11 19:00:00  |  50
2011-11-11 20:00:00  |  53
2011-11-11 22:00:00  |  16
2011-11-12 06:00:00  |  15
2011-11-12 07:00:00  |  150
```

The date 2011-11-11 21:00:00 and the range between 23 pm and 5am is missing. For these dates there should be a row in the result-table (containing a 0 in the value-column).

I hope you understand my problem. If something is unclear, please comment. Thank you.

Comment: You can't have a single query "make" a fake table that contains a full range of data to join against. That's not a query's job. Which is why the usual solution is to create a temp table, populated with ALL of the dates and then join. Creating that table is NOT the db server's job. It's yours. If all you need those missing values for is display purposes, then just fill in the blanks in your display code.

Comment: Why do I get downvotes? I just want to know something and try to describe it good. If you think there´s a problem with it, then vote to close or to delete

Comment: I haven't down-voted, but I suspect you're going at this problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It seems so... I just thought that it would be effective when the database contains the **pure data** and the query delivers me the **data I need**, so that I can bind the output to the view without having to alter it

Answer (score 2):

With SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to generate values out of nothing:

```
WITH RECURSIVE AllDates(accdate)
AS (VALUES('2011-11-11 00:00:00')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datetime(accdate, '+1 hour')
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE accdate < '2011-11-12 10:00:00')
SELECT AllHours.accdate,
       MyTable.value
FROM AllHours
LEFT JOIN MyTable USING (accdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to use a left join with the same table, adding to the desired field on the join and union the result with the actual results to complete the set:

Example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
    id INT IDENTITY,
    number INT
);

-- insert some incomplete sequenced values
INSERT INTO tmp (number) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO tmp (number) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO tmp (number) VALUES(4);
```

Example query:

```
-- select your actual data
SELECT number
FROM tmp

UNION

-- select the missing data
SELECT a.number + 1
FROM tmp a
LEFT JOIN tmp b ON a.number + 1 = b.number
WHERE b.id IS NULL

-- order the complete set
ORDER BY number ASC;
```

**This will not work if you have more than one missing value between your results (eg.: 1 and 4)**, but if your data misses only single hours between each result this Works like a charm.